# Convert String to Boolean and insert in external database via `BasicNameValuePair`

Tags: android, mysql

I need to insert spinner selected from the users to my external database which has a column datatype of `bit` which I believe is a `Boolean`.

I'm taking the spinner user selection as String converting it to boolean as below as the spinner only contains `Yes` or `N/A`. However, I researched and found out that `String "Yes"` returns a boolean value of `false` therefore I converted it to `True` first and then to `Boolean` as below:

```
spinnerText1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (spinnerText1.equals("Yes"))
        {
            String convSpinnerText1 = "True"; 

            spinnerBoo1 = Boolean.parseBoolean(convSpinnerText1);
        }
        if(spinnerText1.equals("N/A"))
        {
            spinnerBoo1 = Boolean.parseBoolean(spinnerText1);
        }
```

Inserting the boolean value in the BasicNameValuePair as it only accept Strings in it:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fl_atms_fan_assst_fan_diltn_chk",String.valueOf(spinnerBoo1)));
```

But it's not working. Can someone please tell where I am going wrong ? Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `spinnerBoo1 = spinnerText1.equals( "Yes" );`?

Comment: I tried however, still the same :(

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> spinnerText1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
>     if (spinnerText1.equals("Yes"))
>        spinnerBoo1 = true;
>    if(spinnerText1.equals("N/A"))
>        spinnerBoo1 = false;
> ```

You cant convert a string into a boolean.

Comment: Still not changing anything and you can convert String to Boolean according to [this](http://www.javadb.com/convert-string-to-boolean/)